# JQuery translator

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to translate words into pirate words.

So this code has it so that it tries to take words from a box into a function that should change the words into a "pirate" translation but it doesn't show the translation. Please tell me how to look for errors or begin debugging this code that I don't understand at all.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- CC BY-NC-ND https://responsivevoice.org/ -->
  <script src='https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js'></script>
  
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <h2>Normal</h2>
  <textarea id="normal"></textarea>

  <h2>Pirates</h2>
  <textarea id="pirate"></textarea>

  <p>
    
    <input onclick='speak()' type='button' value=' Talk like a pirate' />
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#normal").keyup(function(){

          var r = $("#normal").val();
          
          let c = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz';
          for(let letter of r){
            let smallLetter = letter.toLowerCase();
            r = r + letter;
            if(c.includes(smallLetter)){
              
              r = r + 'o' + smallLetter;  
              
              
            }
          }
          return r;

          words = words.replace(r);
          $("#pirate").val(r);

        });
      });

      function speak(){
        var text = $("#pirate").val();
        responsiveVoice.speak(text);
      }
      
    </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: remove `return r;` from your code.It is ending your function and you can not print your newly created words to `#pirate` input.

Comment: it still doesnt work when i took that away D:

Comment: Now it is printing the words that im writing AND the translation right after. So its working but i need to get the words that im writing out of there xD

Comment: Can you provide your code on codepen or jsfiddle without Speech API requests.

Comment: Sure thing! https://codepen.io/MrLowBot/pen/zYKGMMP

Comment: It works well on codepen? What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that i get my words that i write printed into the other box as well as the new translated words..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I removed `return r;`. It was ending your function and you couldn't print your newly created words to `#pirate` input.

Second, you were using the same variable to store your changing, `r = r + letter;` and `r = r + 'o' + smallLetter`. I changed them with a new variable which name is d in the beginning on the function and returned it.

Note: I removed your Speech API from the answer.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#normal").keyup(function(){

        var r = $("#normal").val();
      let d= "";
          let c = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz';
          for(let letter of r){
            let smallLetter = letter.toLowerCase();
            d = d + letter;
            if(c.includes(smallLetter)){

              d = d + 'o' + smallLetter;  
           }
          }

        $("#pirate").val(d);

    });
});
```

```html
<!-- Av Karwan Maryame Azar.-->


<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <h2>Normal</h2>
<textarea id="normal"></textarea>

<h2>Pirates</h2>
<textarea id="pirate"></textarea>

<p>
  
<input type='button' value=' Talk like a pirate' />
  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would i be able to add my text to speech? I tried adding it in but it doesnt want to work... https://codepen.io/MrLowBot/pen/zYKGMMP

Comment: @MrLowBot It works great on codepen with text to speech.

Answer (score 1):

On line #35 you are appending your concatenated result to the entire value.

```
r = r + letter;
```

You should probably use a new variable for your final result and let r be a variable for the original text only.